# What status should be implemented when bg is called in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell, operating-system

Well guys I am learning job-control of a linux operating system.

I am coding a shell which simulate the `bg` feature of bash-shell

so when I use main process to `kill(child_process, SICCONT)`

what should the main process wait for the pid?

I use `waitpid(-1,NULL,WUNTRACED)` for fg

but I don't know about the bg.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For background processes, you want the parent to continue. So use `WNOHANG` to check if any of the children exited, if not parent can continue.